# Mask rotated/curvilinear grid (NetCDF) with rectilinear grid (geotiff)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, netcdf, pyproj, rioxarray

I have two datasets:

Climate:

- avg one month temperature
- NetCDF File (CF Convention 1.6)
- grid_mapping_name: rotated_latitude_longitude (with rlat and rlong coordinates defining the grid)
- curvilinear grid

Harvest Area Fraction:

- Wheat
- Geotiff File
- EPSG: 4326 (lon and lat coordinates defining the grid)
- rectilinear grid

I managed to plot both datasets (see picture below).

I want to extract the climate data values where the wheat grows. However, the two datasets have different coordinate systems (rotated lon/lat grid vs. regular lon/lat grid), so they do not align.

Suggestions?

[image]

**EDIT**:
If I call `climatedata.rio.crs` I get the following output:

```
GEOGCRS["undefined",BASEGEOGCRS["undefined",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],ID["EPSG",6326]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8901]]],DERIVINGCONVERSION["Pole rotation (netCDF CF convention)",METHOD["Pole rotation (netCDF CF convention)"],PARAMETER["Grid north pole latitude (netCDF CF convention)",39.25,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],PARAMETER["Grid north pole longitude (netCDF CF convention)",198,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],PARAMETER["North pole grid longitude (netCDF CF convention)",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
```

**EDIT**:

Step 1: Transform climate data to regular spaced lon-lat grid.

```
climatedata =  xa.open_dataset(r'filepath.nc', decode_cf = True, decode_coords = "all")
df = climatedata.squeeze().to_dataframe().reset_index()
geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df.lon, df.lat)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=climatedata.rio.crs, geometry=geometry)
geo_grid = make_geocube(vector_data=gdf, resolution=(-0.1, 0.1), rasterize_function=rasterize_points_griddata,)
geo_grid = geo_grid.tas_moy[:,:]
```

[image]

`geo_grid.rio.crs` is the same as mentioned above. `harvestdata.rio.crs` is the following:

```
GEOGCS["unknown",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["unknown",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST]]
```

Step 2: Reproject climate data to harvest data:

```
harvestdata = xa.open_dataset(r'filepath.tif')
climatedata_matched = geo_grid.rio.reproject_match(harvestdata)
```

Problem: climatedata_matched is an array only with NaN values.
[image]

Comment: What coordinate system is your climate data in?

Comment: The climate data has no 'crs' attribute. If I call 'climatedata.rio.crs', the output is posted above. I already tried to important an CRS object from the CF convention, but it returned no epsg code to me [link](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/build_crs_cf.html#importing-crs-from-cf). Is there another why to get the coordinate system?

Comment: Is it possible to share your files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Determine the CRS & coordinates for each one

For the climate grid with 2D coordinates, this may be a helpful reference: https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/209

Step 2: Re-project to the same grid

https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject_match.html

I recommend re-projecting the climate grid to the harvest grid.

Comment: Very helpful post #209! Problem: The new matched climate grid only contains NaN values. Any suggestions? I will add my code to the question above.

Comment: You could try passing in the harvest grid into `like=` when making the geocube.

Comment: Passing `like=harvest data` works. But the new plot has "stripes" meaning that the values for one x are the same along the y axis. Is this due to the rasterize function? That's why I tried `rasterize_function=partial(rasterize_points_griddata, method="cubic")` to keep the high resolution from the original data, but again I only get NaN values.

Comment: Afer analysing the data, my assumption is that `reproject_match` cannot read `geo_grid.rio.crs` (see output above). If I write a crs attribute manually to the geo_grid (`geo_grid.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)`)  then the `reproject_match` seems to work, because the array has values (not only NaN). Now my question is, how do I get the right epsg code from the climate data (netcdf)? Epsg:4326 was just a random assumption to try it out.

Comment: I am still not sure how to convert the wkt from `climatedata.rio.crs` (see above) to an epsg code. `climatedata.rio.crs.to_epsg()` returns `none`. Any suggestions on how to get the epsg code from the netcdf climate data?

Comment: Not all CRS have an EPSG code.

Comment: but how can I transform the wkt string `climatedata.rio.crs` so that the crs attribute can be interpreted by `reproject_match()`?

Comment: What version of GDAL/PROJ are you using?

Comment: GDAL: 3.4.1 and pyproj 3.3.0

Comment: Related to this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431605/144357

Comment: yes, it is related to that issue.