# How to convert crs_wkt starting with GEOGCRS to a ogc_wkt string (to use rioxarray.reproject_match)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, netcdf, epsg, rioxarray

I have two xarray data arrays (1. land_data, 2. climate_data) that I want to reproject and match ([rio.reproject_match()](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.reproject_match)):

```
climate_data_matched = climate_data.rio.reproject_match(land_data)
```

1. Land data is a geotiff file with `land_data.rio.crs`  = `EPSG:4326`. The crs attribute is accepted by `rio.reproject_match()`.
2. Climate data is a netcdf file with `climate_data.rio.crs` =

> GEOGCRS["undefined",BASEGEOGCRS["undefined",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],ID["EPSG",6326]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8901]]],DERIVINGCONVERSION["Pole rotation (netCDF CF convention)",METHOD["Pole rotation (netCDF CF convention)"],PARAMETER["Grid north pole latitude (netCDF CF convention)",39.25,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],PARAMETER["Grid north pole longitude (netCDF CF convention)",198,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],PARAMETER["North pole grid longitude (netCDF CF convention)",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[1](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.reproject_match),ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[2](https://www.spatialreference.org),ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]]

However, `rio.reproject_match()` does
only support OGC WKT (from [spatialreference.org](https://www.spatialreference.org)).

**PROBLEM:** If I run the code as described above, the climate_data array is empty (NaN values).

My assumption is that the prefix GEOGCRS cannot be interpreted and instead I need to convert the wkt to a string starting with GEOGCS (in line with OGC WKT). How can I convert them? I converted `crs = climate_data.rio.crs.to_proj4()` and then wanted to use [pycrs](https://pypi.org/project/PyCRS/#parsing-from-proj4-string) to `crs = pycrs.parse.from_proj4(crs)` and `crs = pycrs.parse.from_ogc_wkt(crs)`. But I got an error parsing the proj4 string: "The specified projection name 'ob_tran' could not be found in the list of supported projections."

If I manually modify the crs of climate_data `climate_data = climate_data.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)` and then run the code from above `rio.reproject_match()` works perfectly fine. But I do not know whether `'EPSG:4326'` is actually to right code for the climate_data. How can I get the EPSG code from the wkt string starting with GEOGCRS?

Furthermore, I found [this](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/issues/370) issue that proj4 failed in the past with GEOGCRS. And GEOGCRS is also defined in [opengeospatial.org](https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html#70).

Comment: Maybe you should update the reading program. The WKT standard says "If the WKT begins with or contains any of the following keywords, it is an older format: COMPDCS, FITTED_CS, GEOCCS, GEOGCS, LOCAL_CS, PROJCS, VERT_CS. The last characters in all these keywords are 'CS'."

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/431267/edit) to include the full WKT string please

Comment: 1. The land data is an EPSG code and the climate data is contains the keyword GEOGCRS. so it seems that it is not an older format. 2. I added the full WKT. Maybe FYI: The climate data was a rotated grid data I changed to a regular grid. But I did not change the CRS attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like "Pole rotation (netCDF CF convention)" was added in PROJ 8.2:

- https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/2835
- https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/948

Requires PROJ >= 8.2 to work. So, you need to have your version of pyproj/GDAL built against PROJ >= 8.2.